# Reading variable list into sas macro

Tags: variables, macros, sas

I asking an old question. I have the code and have looked to previous questions but nevertheless I am unable to correct my mistake. Below is the code with dummy data. I am unable to pass the names of variables to the macro.

```
data x;                                                                                                                                 
inputs x$ y z;                                                                                                                          
datalines;                                                                                                                              
 a 23 34                                                                                                                                
b 34 43                                                                                                                                 
a 23 54                                                                                                                                 
b 87 78                                                                                                                                 
a 12 32                                                                                                                                 
b 22 33                                                                                                                                 
;                                                                                                                                       
run;
```

Now I create a list of variables

```
 %let name_list=y z;
```

Then I write macro.

```
 %macro mixed;                                                                                                                        
   %let j=1;                                                                                                                            
   %let first=%scan(&name_list.,%eval(&j));                                                                                             
   %do %while (&first ne );                                                                           

       proc mixed data=x;                                                                                                           
             class x;                                                                                                               
             model &name_list.=;                                                                                                    
             random x;                                                                                                              
    ods output covParms=cov1;                                                                                                       
    run;                                                                                                                  
    %let j=%eval(&j+1);                                                                                                               
      %let first=%scan(&name_list.,%eval(&j));                                                                                          
    %end;                                                                                                                                
   run;                                                                                                                                 
%mend;                                                                                                                                  

%mixed;
```

Some how this is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your macro code works (though could be improved).  What does "not working" mean?  What is the MODEL statement you are trying to generate for PROC MIXED?  Right now you are generating `model y z=;` which could be the problem.

Comment: Adding `options mprint mlogic symbolgen;` before the macro invocation could at least help with diagnosis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the names in a list then you can just use a normal `%DO ... %TO` loop. No need to manually initialize or increment the counter.

```
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&name_list));
  %let name=%scan(&name_list,&i);
 .... place code here that uses &NAME ....
%end;
```

Comment: Agree, the creation of COUNTW (in early v9?) made looping through a list of items much easier. I usually specify the delimiter for countw, i.e. `%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&name_list,%str( )));` so that if the list is null it will return 0 instead of an error.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. Now I want to append the result in one dataset. Nevertheless I have an idea and will work on it. Responses are appreciated.

Comment: Use PROC APPEND to aggregate the result sets together.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Will try this. I did it the otherway which was ugly!